# Error with React app when trying to remove bootstrap classes in ComponentDidMount and even in Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to loop over and remove and replace bootstrap classes in my React Application.

It works fine if I just use a button click to call function that does this.  Either way the ID shows with console.log .

I'm confused at I thought **ComponenentDidMount** is ok to use , but then I decide to use  **Render**() method and I still get the error of

```
 // displays fine in ComponentDidMount and in Render 
 console.log('in loop render id sending over is:', this.state.data[i]["Member_ID"]);

 // error with this  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null` 
 document.getElementById(this.state.data[i]["Member_ID"]).classList.remove('btn-warning');
```

So to summarize:   No idea with a button calling function and removing the class bootstrap  ( i replace the class after etc...)

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null`

How can i achieve this?  Timer?  A different lifecycle method?

Comment: It would probably be better to address this by overriding the CSS, running a class replacement on every render is going to cause a lot of unnecessary re-renders and could expose weird loading appearances.  If you only want to change the CSS for ```bin-warning```, you can just add in your own CSS overriding the rules you don't want.

Comment: Ok , @RutherfordWonkington  currently i can't get it to work in render or in componentdidmount , so I have no idea how to even do this.   I certainly don't want it to be slow, but i can't even find any article or example on what i'm trying to do.  Can you show me an example or sample or website link?   thx

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish exactly.  You can just write CSS to override the styles you don't want.